# Program hangs when i redirect console output to richtextbox

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

when i invoke the external exe from code and redirect output to my UI richtextbox after sometime the UI hangs and not shows the output on the screen, It slowly starts delay the output on the UI screen, any one have idea why this is happening.Here's my code

```
private void RunExe(string arg)
    {
        var cmdStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            Arguments = arg,
            FileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, @"Demo.exe"),
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
        };
        _cmd = new Process {StartInfo = cmdStartInfo};
        _cmd.OutputDataReceived +=new DataReceivedEventHandler(OutputHandler);
        _cmd.Start();
        ProcessId = _cmd.Id;
        _enableButton = new Task(_cmd_Exited);
        _enableButton.Start();
        MyTabControl.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        if (!MyTabControl.Items.Contains(ConsoleTabItem))
        {
            MyTabControl.Items.Add(ConsoleTabItem);
        }
        txtConsoleOutput.Document.Blocks.Clear();
        ConsoleTabItem.Focus();
        ConsoleTabItem.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        ConsoleTabItem.IsEnabled = false;
        _cmd.BeginOutputReadLine();
        LoadResults();
    }
```

And for the output handler

```
private void OutputHandler(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.Data != null)
            {
                string line;
                Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    line = e.Data;
                    if (line != null)
                    {
                        txtConsoleOutput.AppendText(line + "\n");
                        ConsoleScrollerView.ScrollToBottom();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
```

I'll really appreciate for any help ..Thanks

Comment: How long it is taking to reflect in the screen i.e in the form? Did you tried the demo.exe privately and monitored how long it is taking to print the output?

Comment: Can you check the delay after shifting  _cmd.BeginOutputReadLine(); to next after _cmd.start()?

Comment: initially it works fine but as exe runs for longer time it delays the output and also affect the own functionality of exe. e.g. if exe is performing some actions, the time of output will grow with the time of exe running

Comment: It is very easy to fire-hose the UI thread with too many Invoke() calls.  Easy to diagnose with Task Manager, you'll see your program burning 100% core.  You must limit the number of invokes to a reasonable rate, buffer the strings yourself first, don't invoke until at least 50 msec has passed.  And yes, it does inevitably get worse the longer your program runs, you constantly ask RTB to reallocate its text buffer.  Fire-hosing the GC heap, compare String vs StringBuilder.  You must throw away old text so this cannot grow without bound.